# crystal reports Issue in path file

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-8.5

After making a published version of asp.net webform application and uploading it to my clients server the application worked correctly.

But after time it showed this error:

```
at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened() 
    at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob) 
    at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename) 
    at LogisticSystem.eokReports.ExportReportPage.GetReport() 
    in D:\Mostafa\LogisticSystem\LogisticSystem\eokReports\ExportReportPage.aspx.cs:line 390
```

this path is my local pc path

"D:\Mostafa\LogisticSystem\LogisticSystem\eokReports\ExportReportPage.aspx.cs" not a path at the clients server

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. I would suggest you to use the formatting capabilities of the question editor. I would also suggest you to actually ask a question.

Comment: i need your help for answer this question

Comment: This is the point i tried to make clear. You didn't ask a question.

Comment: If you have solved the issue you might want to share what caused the error and what fixed your problem and then set the question to answered.

Comment: i need your help to solve this error

Comment: Then either your filepath is incorrect or there is a permissions issue. Can you please post more of your code in your question?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to load a file that is not present at the clients server. Make sure that your report path is correct and the file exists. If `"D:\Mostafa\LogisticSystem\LogisticSystem\eokReports\ExportReportPage.aspx.cs" not a path at the clients server` is your error, then it's pretty clear that the file path you specify in your code does not exist on the server. Put the report file on the client's server and change your code to point to that file location instead of the location on YOUR machine.

Hope that helps,

Chris